# Android icon resolution

Tags: android, android-icons

According to this [link](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) it would be great to provide 48x48, 72x72 and 92x92.
My question, do I need to maintain the same resolution across all different size image? Or different sizes of images with different resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same link you provided gives you the answer. The resolution should be different for each size :

- 48x48   : ~160 dpi
- 72x72   : ~240 dpi
- 96x96   : ~320 dpi
- 144x144 : ~480 dpi

You should also note that they provided the 48x48 as an example (which works fine for icons) but that the scaling also works for every image you have to use in your application.

An other example would be a 16x16 image (which would be a small contextual icon like a star), you would use the same resolution for each tier, but the size would differ, like so :

- 16x16 : ~160 dpi
- 24x24 : ~240 dpi
- 32x32 : ~320 dpi
- ...

Comment: i tot i just only need to focus on the size of the images. Seems like need more effort in creating in different resolution.

Comment: I'd say that as long as your base image is of a high resolution/high size you can just scale back the images at the right size. But you can always compress the images for the low density screens. As long as the images don't look fuzzy on a phone, you're good.

Comment: so, as long as I provide 1 high res image, Android will help me to resize/scale it accordingly to low and medium resolution phone?

Comment: Yes, but [there are drawbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483990/android-only-use-xxhdpi-images). You can always scale them properly beforehand.